# Add data to View from additional Table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I would like to call a Create View from the "Buchungen" controller.
To do this, I would like to add some data from another table (ArWoo) to the view so that it is already filled out in advance.

The two tables are not linked.

I give the appropriate ID when calling the "Buchungen" controller.

```
    // GET: Buchungen/Create_AR
    public IActionResult Create_AR(int? id)
    {

        var AR = _context.ArWoo
            .Where(n => n.Id == id);

        ViewData["Bestellnummer"] = AR.Bestellnummer;
        return View("Create");
    }
```

How can I now transfer a value from AR (e.g. "Bestellnummer") to the view?

I thought that would just go along with ViewData["Bestellnummer"] = AR.Bestellnummer;
But this doesn´t work.

If I set a breakpoint at return View ("Create"), I see that the variable AR is correctly assigned.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOmv3.jpg)

Comment: Can you post your view too pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix the action by adding FirstOrdefault to a query

```
public IActionResult Create_AR(int? id)
    {

        var AR = _context.ArWoo
            .Where(n => n.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();

        ViewData["Bestellnummer"] = AR.Bestellnummer;

       // or return View("Create",AR.Bestellnummer);

        return View("Create");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the solution.